# _Resolving "AssertionError: emit called after event handler completed" in Flutter Bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc

Hello Flutter & Bloc Community,

I am experiencing an issue with my ChannelsBloc in Flutter where I encounter an _AssertionError related to calling emit after an event handler has completed. The error message I receive is:

```
_AssertionError ('package:bloc/src/emitter.dart': Failed assertion: line 114 pos 7: '!_isCompleted': 
emit was called after an event handler completed normally.
I/flutter ( 9415): emit was called after an event handler completed normally.
I/flutter ( 9415): This is usually due to an unawaited future in an event handler.
I/flutter ( 9415): Please make sure to await all asynchronous operations with event handlers
I/flutter ( 9415): and use emit.isDone after asynchronous operations before calling emit() to
I/flutter ( 9415): ensure the event handler has not completed.
```

This issue arises in my Bloc which is responsible for fetching and managing a list of SchoolModel objects, handling pagination. Here's the relevant part of my ChannelsBloc:

```
class ChannelsBloc extends Bloc<ChannelsEvent, ChannelsState> {
  final List<SchoolModel> _channels = [];
  int _currentPage = 0;

  ChannelsBloc() : super(const ChannelsState.initial()) {
    on<ChannelsEvent>((event, emit) {
      event.when(
        fetchChannels: () async {
          if (_channels.isEmpty) {
            add(const ChannelsEvent.started());
          } else {
            // Fetch the next page
            final newSchools = await onNearby(_currentPage + 1);
            if (newSchools.isEmpty) {
              emit(ChannelsState.noMore(_channels, _currentPage));
            } else {
              _channels.addAll(newSchools);
              _currentPage++;
              emit(ChannelsState.loaded(_channels, _currentPage));
            }
          }
        },
        started: () async {
          _currentPage = 0;
          _channels.clear();

          try {
            final newSchools = await onNearby(_currentPage + 1);
            if (!isClosed) {
              if (newSchools.isNotEmpty) {
                _channels.addAll(newSchools);
                _currentPage++;
                emit(ChannelsState.loaded(_channels, _currentPage)); //fails here
              } else {
                emit(ChannelsState.noMore(_channels, _currentPage)); //fails here
              }
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print('Error fetching data: $e');
            // Handle errors or emit an error state as needed
          }
        },
        refreshChannels: () {
          _currentPage = 0;
          _channels.clear();
          add(const ChannelsEvent.fetchChannels());
        },
      );
    });
  }
}
```

The error seems to occur when I attempt to emit new states after asynchronous fetch operations within the fetchChannels and started event handlers.

**UI**

```
BlocBuilder<ChannelsBloc, ChannelsState>(
                bloc: GetIt.instance<ChannelsBloc>()
                  ..add(const ChannelsEvent.fetchChannels()),
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return state.when(
                    initial: () => Container(),
                    loaded: (schools, _) {
                      return GraphQLListView<SchoolModel>(
                        items: schools,
                        itemBuilder: (school) =>
                            ListTile(title: Text(school.sh_name)),
                        onEndReached: () {
                          // Dispatch the event to load more data
                          // GetIt.instance<ChannelsBloc>()
                          //     .add(const ChannelsEvent.fetchChannels());
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    noMore: (schools, _) {
                      // Handle the state when no more items are available
                      return const Text("No More to show");
                    },
                  );
                },
              )
```

Thank you